# Searching words from dictionary in txt and returning values

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

### My function supposed to find words from dictionary in text, then add values together in *"points"* variable.

But I messed something up. My process as follows:

1. Dictionary:

   ```
   words = {'very funny': 3,'funny': 2,'accidentally funny': 1}
   ```
2. Text file (called: sample.txt):

> Monty Python is very funny. +3
> Some standups are funny. +2
> Politicians are sometimes accidentally funny. +1
> Real pythons are not funny at all. +2

*the values represent score I wanted to achieve for each line

3. Taking text from .txt file:

   ```
   with open('sample.txt', 'r') as text:
       data = text.read()
   ```
4. Function:

   ```
   def counter(data): #this should find keywords
       default_value = 0 #var for stuff not included in dict
       points = 0 
       for i in data:
           points += words.get(i, default_value)  #using get to avoid valueError
       print(points)
       return points  

   counter(data)
   ```
5. Output:

   ```
   0  

   Process finished with exit code 0
   ```

edit *I knew I forgot about something ;]*:

### Problems

1. My function seem to not count anything still
2. I want to score those key frazes in a way that the single word "funny" will not be tripple scored, but trigger just `'funny': 2` effect. I have no idea how to approach that though.

*This is my first question on stack, so if I've messed something up, please let me know.*

Comment: For being the first question is a really good explained one :D

Comment: What's the expected output for your input?

Comment: @Austin I wanted points to be +3 for 1st line, +2 for 2nd, +1 for 3rd and agiain +2 fo 4th = 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your data structure. In general, dictionaries are good if you want to do look-ups on them. However, that's not what you're doing here. Instead I would advise a list of tuples. So, your `words` would look like this:

```
words = [ ("very funny", 3), ("funny", 2), ("accidentally funny", 1) ]
```

Next, when you run your for loop, you're iterating over each character in the string instead of each word. What you should do instead is iterate over the values in `words` and find the number of occurrences of each word:

```
import re

total = 0
for w in words:
    total += w[1] * sum(re.finditer(w[0], data))
```

However, as has already been pointed out, this will find duplicates. To avoid this, you should order `words` in the order you want to search them in and remove the values you find from `data`:

```
words = [ ("very funny", 3), ("accidentally funny", 1), ("funny", 2) ]

total = 0
for w in words:
    total += len(list(re.finditer(w[0], data))) * w[1]
    data = data.replace(w[0], '')
```

However, this isn't very performant. If you want to make this run faster, I would use an [LL parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser). Basically, you would split your data over whitespace, and iterate over it, pulling the next `k` characters where `k` is the number of words in the longest entry in `words`. You would join those `k` words together using spaces and check to see if they matched any of the entries in `words`. In this case you would want to use the dictionary, by the way. You could do it like this:

```
splitData = data.split(' \r\n')
total = 0
for i in range(0, len(splitData)):

    # Longest entry in words has two words so we use i + 2
    phrase = ' '.join(splitData[i:(i + 2)])
    if (phrase in words):
        total += words[phrase]
```

Of course, this solution assumes all your entries have two words in them, which isn't the case. To solve this problem, make `words` into a dictionary of dictionaries where the top-level dictionary maps a phrase to the number of words it contains:

```
words = {1: {"funny": 2}, 2: {"very funny": 3, "accidentally funny": 1}}
splitData = data.split(' \r\n')
total = 0
i = 0
while (i < len(splitData)):
    for l, mapping in words.items():
        phrase = ' '.join(splitData[i:(i + l)])
        if (phrase in mapping):
            total += mapping[phrase]
            i += 1
            continue
    i++
```

Note that I add `l` to `i` so that we avoid duplicates. Again, you can use tuples instead of a dictionary to assert an order to your search. Also, I use a while loop here instead of a forloop because you can't actually change the value of a loop invariant inside the loop in Python.

Comment: This looks good! I will try this ASAP. Thank you for explaining step by step. This helps **A LOT**.

Comment: @noobcodes If the solution helps, I would recommend upvoting. Not just for me, but in general.

Comment: I will as soon I check it and as soon as I will get 15 rep. We newbs can't upvote untill then. ;]

Comment: @noobcodes I would also suggest hitting the checkmark on the answer you want to list as the "solution" to your problem. Doesn't necessarily have to be mine but this helps other users looking at your question in the future :)

Comment: In the part before introducing LL parser I get this: 
`total += len(re.finditer(w[0], data)) * w[1]`
`TypeError: object of type 'callable_iterator' has no len()`

Comment: My apologies. I've updated the answer so please take a look

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you reverse your logic - iterate over the terms and count how many times they appear:

```
def counter(data): #this should find keywords
    points = 0 
    for word, value in words.items():
        points += value * data.count(word)
    print(points)
    return points
```

However that means some terms can score more than once - `'very funny'` **contains** `'funny'` too, so it is supposed to be worth 5 (3 from `'very funny'` and 2 from `'funny'`)?

Your text contains 4 `funny`, 1 `very funny` and 1 `accidentally funny` so the result is 4*2 + 3 + 1 = 12

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I wanted to count that as single "funny" sepparate from "very funny" and "accidentally funny". I should write that in post. Will edit that in soon.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'd do. I'd split this text into a list of words then iterate over it. I concatenate each word with the one before it. then look the two-word thing in the dictionary. Of course I can't concatenate the first word with the one before it. So first_iteration variable is only true for the first iteration and gets changed to false at the end of the first iteration to false.
I hope this solves your problem.

```
def counter(data): #this should find keywords
    default_value = 0 #var for stuff not included in dict
    points = 0 
    first_iteration = True
    wordsList = data.split()
    for i in wordList:
        if (!first_iteration):
            theWord = i + " " + prev
        points += words.get(theWord, default_value)  #using get to avoid valueError
        prev = i
        first_iteration = False
    print(points)
    return points  

counter(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

`for I in data` this is the issue. since data is a `str` you're basically iterating through individual characters not complete words.